# How to set a limit of a font size to my buttons

Tags: html, node.js, angular

so, I am trying to make two buttons, one to decrease and one to increase the font size of my text, they work but I would like to set a limited size of how small or big it will get.

Here is what I have in the code:

```
<md-button ng-click="detailsFontSize=detailsFontSize-1" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>  </i> - </md-button>
<md-button ng-click="detailsFontSize=detailsFontSize+1" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>  </i> + </md-button>
```

Comment: As there is no CSS  for minimum or maximum font size, you can use @media queries to  make some CSS settings depending on things like screen or window width

Comment: But, if you are handling the size with your controller, you can handle the logic to set the max and min size

Comment: use ternary operator like below the answer I have added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To limit font size I would suggest using a ternary operator like below.

```
<md-button ng-click="detailsFontSize=detailsFontSize == 12 ? detailsFontSize : detailsFontSize - 1" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>  </i> - </md-button>
<md-button ng-click="detailsFontSize=detailsFontSize == 24 ? detailsFontSize : detailsFontSize + 1" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>  </i> + </md-button>
```

Here I set limit 12 for lowest font size and 28 highest font size you can change as per your convenience.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: thank you TheParam, im new at html and angular, it worked like a charm.

Comment: most welcome @joao  I am glad that solved your problem

Answer (score 0):

I would use css for this, but you can also use min/max:

```
<md-button ng-click="detailsFontSize=Math.max(10, detailsFontSize-1)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>  </i> - </md-button>
<md-button ng-click="detailsFontSize=Math.min(30, detailsFontSize+1)" ><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></i>  </i> + </md-button>
```

For example this limits font size to be in range [10, 30].